# Declarar variables dentro de un bucle o declararlas fuera con llaves que reduzcan su ámbito

Tags: java, c#

hace poco tenía la duda de cuál era la mejor práctica, declarar variables dentro de un bucle o declararlas fuera, teniendo en cuenta que estoy hablando de variables que solo se usarán dentro del bucle:

**opción 1:**

```
String test;
while (condition){
   test = anyFunction();
}
```

**opción 2:**

```
while (condition){
   String test = anyFunction();
}
```

Luego de investigar y hacer algunas pruebas me quedó claro que es mejor práctica la opción 2 por el hecho de que las variables se deben declarar donde su ámbito sea lo más reducido posible para evitar el uso indebido de la variable al finalizar el ciclo y afectar la funcionalidad, entre otros detalles.

Ahora mi pregunta sería la siguiente ¿No sería mejor declarar la variable afuera y reducir el ámbito con el uso de llaves? ¿o sería lo mismo?
Me refiero a estas 2 opciones:

**opción A:**

```
while (condition){
   String test = anyFunction();
}
```

**opción B:**

```
{
 String test;
 while (condition){
    test = anyFunction();
 }
}
//aquí ya no existe la variable test
```

En la opción b coloco las llaves solamente para reducir el ámbito de la variable `test`.
No se si sea esta la mejor opción por el hecho de llenar el código de llaves solo con esa finalidad.

Si el uso de la memoria en las opciones A y B es el mismo entonces sí sería mucho más conveniente la opción A. Pero ahí está mi duda.
Espero sus comentarios
gracias

Comment: Para mi gusto, la opcion B es mucho mas dificil de leer que la A... ahi tenes 3 lineas.. y si tu while tuviera 15 o 20??? como te darias cuenta del ambito... igual, esto me suena a basado en opiniones...

Answer (score 0):

De manera practica te comento: si creas la variable dentro del bucle y tu bucle tiene 10 ciclos, tendras 10 espacios reservados en memoria pero si tu ciclo tiene 1,000,000,000 tendras esos 1,000,000,000 espacios reservados en memoria, puede que te enfrentes a errores de memoria, insuficiente memoria.

En mi experiencia, siempre declara fuera de ciclos o condiciones, inicializas en -1, null o algun valor improbable para confirmar que su valor dentro del ciclo cambio.

Comment: Estas totalente seguro de esto? los compiladores no optimizan esos espacios de memoria? como sabe el compilador cuantos ciclos va a hacer, por ejemplo si tu for es i<n y n se define en tiempo de ejecucion? alguna demostracion de esta respuesta?